# How to implement strstr() without casting away const?

Tags: c, casting, constants

[`strstr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) is a C99-conforming function, the type signature of which is the following:

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

Is it possible to **implement this function** without casting away a `const` somewhere?

For reference, here is [Apple's implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/libsa/strstr.c), and here is [GNU's implementation](http://tsunanet.net/~tsuna/strstr.c.html). Both cast away the `const` at the end.

Comment: You don't need to modify anything (?)

Comment: @sircodesalot How do you actually *write* the function without casting away the `const` in order to return a pointer?

Comment: I agree with you. The return type should be `const char *`.

Comment: But that change would break a huge number of existing codebases.

Comment: @paddy Yes, but at the same time, this conundrum points out the flaw in the design of the `const` keyword. If the `haystack` is actually `const`, e.g. a string literal, then returning a non-const pointer from the function is just plain wrong. OTOH, if `haystack` is not `const`, then implicitly converting it to `const`, only to cast the returned pointer back to non-const, is rather pointless.

Comment: Declaring an a pointer argument `const` (i.e., its target) does *not* mean the target is truly constant.  All it means is that the function will not modify it.  Non-const arguments are passed to functions as const all the time.  But there are a *lot* of problems with `const`.  This is just one of many such examples.

Comment: @user3386109: It's not a flaw in the design of `const`. It's a flaw in the design of `strstr`. For consistency, there should be two different functions, one that works on `const` objects and one that works on non-`const` objects. (C++ does this by requiring two overloaded version of `strstr()`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson The flaw in the design of `const` is that the code can freely cast it away. Hence, it has no semantic meaning. Furthermore, it's used as in-line documentation in function prototypes. It's also used to indicate that variables, e.g. string literals, may be placed in read-only memory. It's also used to mark variables as compile time constants, e.g. `const int N=42;`. That's a mishmash of incompatible uses for a single keyword, and is seriously flawed.

Comment: `const` means read-only, not to be confused with "constant", which means evaluable at compile time. `const int N = 42;` does *not* make `N` a constant expression in C (it does in C++). It certainly does have semantic meaning; casts merely let you explicitlyi override that meaning if you need to. String literals, for historical reasons, are not `const` in C; attempting to modify them has undefined behavior but is not necessarily diagnosed.

Comment: @user3386109: `const` creates compile-time constants in C++, but not in C.

Comment: The flaw is in the design of C -- there's no way to say "the result type has the same const-ness as the actual argument". C++ does this with overloading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't implement `strstr()` without violating `const` correctness somehow.  A cast is the most straightforward way to do that. You can probably hide the violation somehow (for example you could use `memcpy()` to copy the pointer value), but there's no point in doing so.

The problem is that `strstr()` takes a `const char*` that points to a string, and returns a non-`const` `char*` that points into the same string.

For example, this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    const char s[] = "hello";
    char *result = strstr(s, "hello");
    *result = 'H';
    puts(result);
}
```

modifies (or at least attempts to modify) a `const`-qualified object, without using a pointer cast or any other obviously unsafe construct.

Back in 1989, the ANSI C committee *could* have avoided this problem by defining two different functions, say:

```
const char *strcstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
      char *strstr (      char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

one that returns a pointer to a `const char` given a `const` arguments, and another that returns  pointer to a modifiable `char` given a modifiable argument. (C++, which inherits the C standard library, does this by overloading.)

`strstr()` is one of several standard string functions that have this problem.

Comment: The basic problem is that `strstr` predates the concept of `const` in the C language...

Comment: @Chris Dodd: Even if it didn't, I'd say that the current interface would still be more appropriate in C than the above with two functions.

Comment: @AnT: How is an interface that lets you quietly violate `const` correctness more appropriate?

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Simply because it is better to be able to use one function instead of having to choose the appropriate one out of the two. By design, C language lets you quietly violate a lot of things, like violating strict aliasing through implicit conversions to and from `void *`. That's just the way things are in C. Watching over such things and avoiding such violations is often caller's responsibility. `strstr` simply does not *enforce* it, which does not means that the responsibility isn't there.

Comment: @AnT - "By design, C language lets you quietly violate a lot of things" - no kidding, like, silently throwing away return values from functions.  If they had originally required a cast to void at the call site to throw away a return value, otherwise issue a compiler error, millions of bugs where return values (= error codes) (of standard functions!) were not checked would have been ... well, if not eliminated, at least subjected to a programmer's informed look.  But I'm afraid that's just a bugbear of mine ...

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in case of `strstr` (and some other standard functions) is an idiomatic solution, whose intent is to support non-modifying operations on both const and non-const strings with a *single* function.

Yes, in order to implement such a function it necessary to explicitly cast away constness from the input pointer. Note that the cast by itself does not yet physically violate anything (meaning: it does not attempt to modify constant data and does not cause undefined behavior). Yet, it does open the door to such violations by returning a non-const pointer to const data to the caller, i.e. violates the conceptual rules of const-correctness.

An alternative solution would be to provide two versions of the same standard function - a const one and a non-const one - but without C++-style function overloading this would require two distinctive function names, which does not necessarily look like a very good idea (and even with C++-style function overloading it has its issues too).

In this case it is effectively the responsibility of the caller to receive the result into a pointer of the same type as the one that was passed in as an argument. If the argument pointer was const-qualified, it is a very good programming practice to receive the result into a pointer that is const-qualified as well. As long as this guideline is observed, this idiom actually feels right at home in the realm of C language.

Comment: C++ does in fact require const overloads for strstr and friends, see sect. 21.8. What issues do you see with this?